# Creating a tflite interpreter instance causes the kernal to die

Tags: jupyter-notebook, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to test a tflite model that I created in a JupyterNotebooks file. I'm running Python 3.7, and after importing tflite with line:

```
import tflite_runtime.interpreter as tflite
```

and then calling an instance of the interpreter with:

```
interpreter = tflite.Interpreter(model_path=modelPath)
```

(Note the model path is pointing at a .tflite file that I exported). The kernel dies.

Thanks for help
Jack